# Is it possible to set the type of variable or constant to the Protocol Equatable in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

I am new to Swift. I am trying to do something similar to:

```
let e:Equatable? where Equatable.Item == Int = nil
```

Is this possible?

Regards,

shodz

Comment: Can you, please, explain what do you want to achieve?

Comment: What is the goal of this expression? Basically declaring a constant as protocol type is pointless.

Comment: I come from a Java background. In Java we can normally create variable types based on interfaces and assign generic parameters types. I want to know if it is possible to do the same in Swift.

Comment: PATs (protocols with associated types) are not the same thing as interfaces. Many ways of thinking about problems in Java are different in Swift. We can probably be of help if you show what you're actually trying to do, since the above example would be useless in Java, so the lack of a Swift equivalent isn't meaningful. It literally says "the type of `e` is `Int?` in the hardest possible way.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that you can't create a variable based on a protocol.

As the official documentation states:

> A protocol defines a blueprint of methods, properties, and other
>   requirements that suit a particular task or piece of functionality.
>   The protocol can then be adopted by a class, structure, or enumeration
>   to provide an actual implementation of those requirements. Any type
>   that satisfies the requirements of a protocol is said to conform to
>   that protocol.

So the minimal amount of work that is required from the developers side is to create a structure or a class that conforms to a certain protocol, let's say `Equatable`.

Let's take an example from the official documentation again. The `Equatable` protocol is the one that allows two elements of the same type to be compared, so to conform to it an `==(lhs: Type, rhs: Type,)` method needs to be implemented.

```
class StreetAddress {
    let number: String
    let street: String
    let unit: String?

    init(_ number: String, _ street: String, unit: String? = nil) {
        self.number = number
        self.street = street
        self.unit = unit
    }
}

extension StreetAddress: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: StreetAddress, rhs: StreetAddress) -> Bool {
        return
            lhs.number == rhs.number &&
            lhs.street == rhs.street &&
            lhs.unit == rhs.unit
    }
}
```

Only now can two instances of `StreetAddress` be created and compared based on your predicate.

Comment: The "short answer" is not really correct. You can absolutely define a variable based on a protocol as long as it doesn't have an associatedType or Self requirements.

Answer (score 1):

So long as the protocol in question has requirements that use an `associatedType` or use `Self`, you cannot do that. In short, it creates too much ambiguity for the compiler. Equatable has requirements that use `Self`. It's hard to suggest something without knowing your use case, but in many scenarios where you hit upon this, the answer is to bubble the generics up a level (for example, if this line of code is inside of a function, make the function generic over the equatable value, and use the generic type):

```
func doSomething<T: Equatable>(with value: T?) { ... }
```

or, alternatively, to look into [type erasure](https://khawerkhaliq.com/blog/swift-protocols-equatable-part-one/). But it'll probably be easier to offer suggestions if we know a bit more about your use case.